# mysql server doesn't run anymore

Tags: mysql, django

I installed Mysql on OS X Mountain Lion and it worked fine for a while.

I would run it using the command: `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot`

Then, I installed Django and now when I execute the command above, I get:

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Anyone have a very precise solution for this?

Comment: Try checking the logs to see if it's failing to start up somehow.

Comment: have you installed the `mysql-python` binding ?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm quite a newbie when it comes to this kind of stuff.  Can you provide instructions for how to check the "logs".

Answer (score 0):

It's happening becaouse your MySQL hasn't been started, now you have to do it manually. To do so, go to System Preferences >  MySQL and press the button: Start Server.

Done, now works!

Comment: I don't see a MySQL app, icon or button in my System Preferences.  Can I get to it via the menus in System Preferences?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work!!

Found the command below in another post and it starts my server and then the client runs.

sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start

Sorry everyone ... still learning.   I rebooted yesterday for something and I guess that's when the server was stopped.

It's all good now.